# How to check if event has no summary, in google calnedar api?

Tags: javascript, google-api, google-calendar-api

here is code that requests event info, summary doesnt seem to really do anything, have tried:`if (request.summary = 0) {...` But i think this is wrong and gave no results.

What i want is: if event has no summary, instead of "undefined" it would print out defined message.

Any ideas?

```
function GRN() {
    var request = gapi.client.calendar.events.list({
      'calendarId': 'MycalendarID',
      'timeMin': (new Date()).toISOString(),
      'showDeleted': false,
      'singleEvents': true,
      'summary': ,
      'maxResults': 5,
      'orderBy': 'startTime',
      'timeMax':(new Date(tomorrow)).toISOString(),
    });
```

Comment: your problem has nothing to do with `python` and `php` - so don't use this tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if(typeof request.summary == 'undefined') { ... }
```

Or

```
if(!request.summary) { ... }
```

Answer (score 0):

Got it to work like this, thnx  @Sojtin for help :)

```
          if(!event.summary) { 
          event.summary = 'opptatt'
          }
```